# iOS 13 broken tableView.moveRow(at:, to:) animation

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, ios13

I've been using `tableView.moveRow(at: IndexPath, to: IndexPath)` to move rows by swipe to the top of the table view for the previous iOS versions:

```
tableView.moveRow(at: indexPath, to: IndexPath(row: 0, section: 0))
```

The action was performed by moving the row with a nice animation which came for free:

*"For rows that are moved, the moved row animates straight from the starting position to the ending position."* - Apple Developer Documentation

I've found that the animation in iOS 13 is limited to the other rows moving down to make space, while the moving row will disappear and reappear on the top of the table view.

Is there a different way to perform this in iOS 13?
It still works fine under iOS 12 or lower.

Comment: Still the same issue on iOS 13.1.

Comment: Can anyone confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't seem to be the case, Animations still occur as normal and expected in UITableView, here is a simple demo example of the move animations in IOS 13.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/R64o5l4oNy8

Can you share some video or visual example if other wise

Comment: Hello dexyjones, thank you for your reply. Please read closely, "move rows -> by swipe <- " You can adjust your example by adding the trailingSwipe method and call tableView.moveRow(at:, to:) in the action handler.